# MySQL Concatenating percentage symbol to input string in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored Procedure which searches my customer Database based on 3 fields.
If the user does not enter a value for a certain field i want to apply a % wildcard so it will not limit the search for that field.
So i am looking for a way to stick a % at the end of my Parameter. Tried 
p_name + '%' and p_name & '%' with no luck

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_customer_search`(
IN p_customer_id varchar(20),
IN p_name varchar(60),
IN p_dba varchar(60)
)
BEGIN

SELECT  customer_id, quicken_id, status,name,dba,city,zip 
FROM tbl_customer
where customer_id like p_customer_id
and name like p_name 
and dba like p_dba;
END
```

Comment: have You tried: `CONCAT(p_name, '%')`  ?

Comment: Yes that did the trick thanks, sometimes one does not think about the simple things :)

Comment: Why not just run the query directly instead of wrapping it in a stored procedure? There's nothing fancy going on here.

Comment: Just a personal preference as it allows me to control the query without having to touch my RestAPI, i am sure there is no performance gain